# Search a sorted array that ends with zeros in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures, search-algorithms

I have an array of size $m$, $[1,1,2,2,3,4,5,...,f,0,0, \cdots,0]$, where the first $n$ elements $1,1,2,2,3,4,5,\cdots, f$ are sorted.

If I make a binary search including the 0's I get $O(\log(m))$.
I'm trying to make the algorithm better and to get complexity of $O(\log(n))$ with no success.

I thought maybe something with medians?
Any idea will be great.

Comment: Each comparison reveals 1 bit of information

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Bulat's hint is sort of cryptic. Here is a different hint. Can you find $n$ or any number that is between $n$ and $2n$ in $O(\log n)$ time?

Comment: @Apass.Jack can you explain please... Why between n to 2n? What that's mean? I can find a number in binary search. But with O(log(m))

Comment: If you find any number between $n$ or $2n$ (or any $cn$ for a constant $c\ge1$), you can treat that number as $m$. Then you can find a number by binary search with $O(\log m)=O(\log n)$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack  Ok. I thought about what you said. So what you suggest is to split the array for x parts, then each array binary search is O(logm) that is equesls to O(logn). That's what you said right?

Comment: Here is my last hint before posting an answer, reverse binary search.

Comment: Check positions number $1,2,4,8,\ldots$ until you find a zero. This takes time $O(\log n)$, and finds a position between $n$ and $2n$. You can then perform binary search as usual.

Comment: @motis10 If n is not small compared to m (say n >= sqrt (m)), then O(log n) and O (log m) are the same, so no problem. When n is small, you need to find a zero at a position not much larger than n in O (log n), and then you can do binary search in O (log n) as well. That's why you need to find a 0 between position n and 2n quickly. Yuval's last hint shows you how.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm to solve the problem as in Yuval's comment.

#### Algorithm

**Input**: A positive number $w$ and array $A$ of $m$ numbers, $A[0],\cdots, A[m-1]$. The first $n$ numbers of $A$ are non-decreasing positive numbers and the rest are 0s.

**Output**: An index $k$ such that $A[k]=w$ or -1 if $w$ is not an element of $A$.

**Procedure**:

1. Check elements at index $1,2,4,8,\cdots$, until a zero is found or the index overflows. Let the index thus found be $p_0$. Let $p$ be the smaller of $p_0$ and $m-1$. Note $n\le p\lt 2n$.
2. Consider 0 as greater than all positive numbers so that $A[0], A[1], \cdots, A[p]$ becomes a sorted array. Conduct a binary search for $w$ on that array. If $w$ is found, return the index; Otherwise, return -1.

#### Algorithm analysis

Step 1 checks at most $\log_2(2n)=1+\log_2 n$ elements. Step 2 checks at most $\log_2(p+1) + 1 \le 2 + \log_2n$ elements. So the time-complexcity of the algorithm is $O(\log n)$.

This problem is a variation of the classic problem of searching sorted, unbounded/infinite lists. The algorithm above is a simple variation of the exponential search explained in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search). You are encouraged to take a look at that article for more intriguing variations. For example, [a basic version of Bentley and Yao's algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Exponential_search&oldid=860785584#Alternatives) checks elements at index 2, 4, 16, 256, 65536, $\cdots$ first.

#### Exercises

**Exercise 1**. (One minute or two) Assume that $w$ might not be positive and the first $n$ element of $A$ might not be positive instead. Adapt the algorithm slightly so that it still works.

**Exercise 2**. (One minute or two) Improve the algorithm so that it runs in $O(\log k)$ time where $k$ is the smaller of $n$ and the index of the first element in $A$ that is no less than than $w.$

**Exercise 3**. Let $B$ be a sorted array of $n$ distinct elements, one of which is $w$. Devise an algorithm that finds $w$'s index in $O(\min(k, n-k))$ time, where $k$ is $w$'s index.